# Expected 2 arguments , but got 1 in angular build prod

Tags: angular, typescript

If i serve my angular app normally it works , but if I try to serve in prod mode it gives me this error and I really dont know where is the problem..

```
//error on build: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.

<ion-col class="ion-no-padding" size-md="12" size-lg="12" size-sm="12" size-xs="12" 
*ngFor="let i=index; let post of person$ | async | sortPipe">
```

**page.ts**

```
 //vars;
  personSubject = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);
  person$: Observable<any> = this.personSubject.asObservable();
  private destroy$ = new Subject();

 getAllPosts() {
    this.authService.getAllPosts().pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe((res: any) => {

      const lenght = res.length;
      console.log(lenght);

      this.getFullPosts = res.data.post;
      this.personSubject.next(res.data.post)
      this.userGallery = res.data.post.forEach(img => {
        img.galleryImages = img.images.map(image => {
          return new ImageItem({ src: image, thumb: image });
        });

      

      })
    });
```

Comment: can you provide minimal reproduce steps to find out the issue?

Comment: The ng-serve is less strict when it comes to errors than ng-build. The compiler should tell you in which file / line the error occurred. Most of the time, this error suggests that a method which accepts only 1 argument was used on a template, where two arguments are passed.

Comment: I tried both ng serve and ng build with prod flag but i always get the same error.. The thing is in normal build it works and my api gets called successfuly idk why program sees an error :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

I didn't had all the propertiers declared in my `SortPipe`.